# How to remove extra canvas margin from QwtPlot

Tags: qwt

In QwtPlot there is always added extra space beyond scale that was set (0 to 1000 in this case). In the picture it was marked with red lines. How to remove this extra space, so the plot would have proper scale?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found solution, if qwtPlt is pointer to QwtPlot class, then:

```
qwtPlt->plotLayout()->setAlignCanvasToScales(true);
```